# How to give value in variable while edit form in python

Tags: python, django

I am working on edit form, when i go for edit i want to show pre loaded values for that form, but when i set value in the variable it doesn't working for me,can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? here i have added my whole code

**`views.py`**

```
def add(request,id=None):
    pass
    if request.POST:
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        permialink = request.POST.get("permialink")
        updated_date = request.POST.get("updated_date")
        bodytext = request.POST.get("bodytext")

        page_data = Pages(title=title,permialink=permialink,updated_date=updated_date,bodytext=bodytext)
        page_data.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('crud:index', args=('')))
    else:
        if id is not None:
            page_data = Pages.objects.all().filter(id=id)
            context = {"page_data":page_data}
            return render(request,'polls/add.html',context)
        else:
            return render(request,'polls/add.html')
```

**`add.html`**

```
{% load static %}

{% if page_data %}
     title = page_data.title
     permialink =  page_data.permialink
{% else %}
    title = ''
    permialink = ''
{% endif %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

<form method="post" action="{% url 'crud:add' %}" name="page_form" id="page_form">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ title }}">
    <input type="text" name="permialink" value="{{ permialink }}">
    <input type="text" name="updated_date" value="">
    <input type="text" name="bodytext" value="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: use `model form` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block:

```
{% if page_data %}
    title = page_data.title
    permialink =  page_data.permialink
{% else %}
    title = ''
    permialink = ''
{% endif %}
```

shouldn't be in your `add.html` template. You can't assign variables like that in Django templates.

Instead that logic should be written in Python in your view `add`. Using a Python if/else block give your `context` dict keys `title`/`permialink` with appropriate values. Then they can be directly rendered in the `add.html` template.